# AlpineJS hide button if total is less that offset and limit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, alpine.js

I am trying to hide a button if my total number is less than limit + offset,

**My button**

```
<div @click="loadMore()" x-show="total > (limit + offset)" class="text-center pt-4">
                 <button class="border border-solid border-slate-700 text-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-800 px-4 py-2"> Load More </button>
            </div>
```

**My data in console**

```
action: filterPosts
limit: 6
post_type_js: videos
offset: 0
category: 1094
total: 28
```

I believe the way i have my button set is if total is more than limit + offset how, else hide. but the button is not showing.

Comment: I've duplicated your code and it works without issue. Are you sure your div has a parent element with `x-data` (and thus Alpine is active for the element)? Also, why is your click event registered for your div and not your button element?